# Variables as commands in Bash scripts

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I am writing a very simple Bash script that [tars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) a given directory, encrypts the output of that, and then splits the resultant file into multiple smaller files since the backup media doesn’t support huge files.

I don't have a lot of experience with Bash scripting. I believe I’m having issues with quoting my variables properly to allow spaces in the parameters. The script follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

# This script tars the given directory, encrypts it, and transfers
# it to the given directory (likely a USB key).

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` DIRECTORY BACKUP_DIRECTORY"
    exit 1
fi

DIRECTORY=$1
BACKUP_DIRECTORY=$2
BACKUP_FILE="$BACKUP_DIRECTORY/`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.backup`"

TAR_CMD="tar cv $DIRECTORY"
SPLIT_CMD="split -b 1024m - \"$BACKUP_FILE\""

ENCRYPT_CMD='openssl des3 -salt'

echo "$TAR_CMD | $ENCRYPT_CMD | $SPLIT_CMD"

$TAR_CMD | $ENCRYPT_CMD | $SPLIT_CMD

say "Done backing up"
```

Running this command fails with:

> split: "foo/2009-04-27T14-32-04.backup"aa: No such file or directory

I can fix it by removing the quotes around `$BACKUP_FILE` where I set `$SPLIT_CMD`. But, if I have a space in the name of my backup directory, it doesn't work. Also, if I copy and paste the output from the "echo" command directly into the terminal, it works fine. Clearly there's something I don't understand about how Bash is escaping things.

Comment: Why would you embed $BACKUP_FILE in SPLIT_CMD when you could just put it after $SPLIT_CMD in the pipeline?

Comment: Well I could do that, but at that point there's not really much point in having variables to contain my commands and I may as well just expand it all out as in Juliano's answer below.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Simply don't put whole commands in variables. You'll get into a lot of trouble trying to recover quoted arguments.

Also:

1. Avoid using all-capitals variable names in scripts. It is an easy way to shoot yourself in the foot.
2. Don't use backquotes. Use $(...) instead; it nests better.

---

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) DIRECTORY BACKUP_DIRECTORY"
    exit 1
fi

directory=$1
backup_directory=$2
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S)
backup_file="${backup_directory}/${current_date}.backup"

tar cv "$directory" | openssl des3 -salt | split -b 1024m - "$backup_file"
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll probably do it this way. Seems less elegant to me than having the commands in variables, but I guess that's the nature of bash scripting.

Comment: @wxs: There is nothing elegant whatsoever about putting commands in variables.  You don't gain any type of flexibility; on the contrary, you just cause bugs due to word splitting.  What you might have intended to do is put commands in functions.  You execute functions.  You should never execute variable content.  ever.

Comment: I don't understand 1. care to explain? How/why does it make easier to shoot oneself in the foot?

Comment: ata: Because you might inadvertently clobber environment variables (which are always upper-case) ?

Comment: @ata: see POSIX convention for environment variable names at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- explicitly, all-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the operating system or shell, and names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed to be safe for applications to use without inadvertently modifying shell behavior.

Answer (score 15):

`eval` is not an acceptable practice if your directory names can be generated by untrusted sources. See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for more on why `eval` should not be used, and [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more on the root cause of this problem and its proper solutions, some of which are touched on below:

If you need to build up your commands over time, use arrays:

```
tar_cmd=( tar cv "$directory" )
split_cmd=( split -b 1024m - "$backup_file" )
encrypt_cmd=( openssl des3 -salt )
"${tar_cmd[@]}" | "${encrypt_cmd[@]}" | "${split_cmd[@]}"
```

Alternately, if this is just about defining your commands in one central place, use functions:

```
tar_cmd() { tar cv "$directory"; }
split_cmd() { split -b 1024m - "$backup_file"; }
encrypt_cmd() { openssl des3 -salt; }
tar_cmd | split_cmd | encrypt_cmd
```

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure, but it might be worth running an [eval](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (near "*The args are read and concatenated together"*) on the commands first.

This will let Bash expand the variables *$TAR_CMD* and such to their full breadth (just as the [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) command does to the console, which you say works).

Bash will then read the line a second time with the variables expanded.

```
eval $TAR_CMD | $ENCRYPT_CMD | $SPLIT_CMD
```

Page *[Bash: Why use eval with variable expansion?](https://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion%3F)* looks like it might do a decent job at explaining why that is needed.

Comment: That seems to do it as well, but I feel like it makes everything a little too convoluted. Oh well, I see why people invented other scripting languages.

Comment: This is a major security risk. See BashFAQ #50 for the best-practice alternative: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- and BashFAQ #48 for a description of why `eval` carries risks: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: Good catch @CharlesDuffy, if this is being used on a shared system where other users are granted access to the script to run with elevated rights, it is a risk.

Comment: @Eddie, not just on a shared system, but against data you don't control. If you've got a script mirroring files from a remote server and unpacking them, and those filenames can be modified by someone malicious, `eval` carries unreasonable risks. Sometimes, "malicious" isn't even necessary -- I once saw a major data loss event caused by a buffer overflow dumping *random* content into filenames that were later processed by a sloppily-written script.

Answer (score 4):

There is a point to only put commands and options in variables.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` DIRECTORY BACKUP_DIRECTORY"
    exit 1
fi

. standard_tools    

directory=$1
backup_directory=$2
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S)
backup_file="${backup_directory}/${current_date}.backup"

${tar_create} "${directory}" | ${openssl} | ${split_1024} "$backup_file"
```

You can relocate the commands to another file you source, so you can reuse the same commands and options across many scripts.   This is very handy when you have a lot of scripts and you want to control how they all use tools.  So standard_tools would contain:

```
export tar_create="tar cv"
export openssl="openssl des3 -salt"
export split_1024="split -b 1024m -"
```

Comment: `tar_create` is missing but helped nonetheless

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem for complex arguments. If your `tar_create` was `tar cv --exclude="* *"`, it would have failed in much the same way as the original. And the `export`s do nothing useful here -- these variables are used in the same shell, so polluting subprocess's environment space is simply a waste.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting spaces inside variables such that the shell will reinterpret things properly is *hard*.  It's this type of thing that prompts me to reach for a stronger language.  Whether that's [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), or whatever (I choose Perl, but that's not always for everyone), it's just *something* that will allow you to bypass the shell for quoting.

It's not that I've never managed to get it right with liberal doses of [eval](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), but just that eval gives me the heebie-jeebies (becomes a whole new headache when you want to take user input and eval it, though in this case you'd be taking stuff that you wrote and evaling that instead), and that I've gotten headaches in debugging.

With Perl, as my example, I'd be able to do something like:

```
@tar_cmd = ( qw(tar cv), $directory );
@encrypt_cmd = ( qw(openssl des3 -salt) );
@split_cmd = ( qw(split -b 1024m -), $backup_file );
```

The hard part here is doing the pipes - but a bit of [IO::Pipe](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egbarr/IO-1.2301/IO/Pipe.pm), fork, and reopening [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)), and it's not bad.  Some would say that's worse than quoting the shell properly, and I understand where they're coming from, but, for me, this is easier to read, maintain, and write.  Heck, someone could take the hard work out of this and create a IO::Pipeline module and make the whole thing trivial ;-)

Comment: It's only a hard problem if you *make* it a hard problem by using `eval`. There's no good reason to do that.