# Bash script called with Variable not respecting Quotes

Tags: bash, shell

My goal is to call a script with an variable as it's arguments.  For example, I have the following two files:

```
print_args.sh:
    echo "Length: $#"
    for i in "$@"; do echo "$i"; done

caller.sh:
    ARGS="foo \"Hello, World\" bar"
    ./test.sh $ARGS
```

When I run:

```
./print_args.sh foo "Hello, World" bar
```

`print_args.sh` get's called with 3 arguments:

```
Length 3
foo
Hello, World
bar
```

However, when running it via `caller.sh` instead I get 4 args:

```
Length: 4
foo
"Hello,
World"
bar
```

What's going on here?  How can I get `caller.sh` to perform as expected?

**Note:**  I don't have control over `ARGS` it's passed in as an environment variable.

Comment: Read this answer: [bash - variable containing multiple args with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454624/6176817).

Comment: When you say you have no control over `ARGS`, can you at least specify that a different format is used to separate the arguments?

Comment: What about documenting that the environment variable should be set like `ARGS=(foo "Hello, World" bar)`, is that also not an option?

Comment: Following on from my previous comment, I added a section to my answer to show what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get test_caller.sh to perform as expected?

Use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=( foo "Hello, World" bar )
./test.sh "${args[@]}"
```

If you pass an unquoted variable, then word splitting occurs on its contents before it is passed to `./test.sh`. You are essentially calling:

```
'./test.sh' 'foo' '"Hello,' 'World"' 'bar'
```

Where the single quotes are used to indicate the start and end of words. The double quotes have no syntactic meaning, they are just characters in a string at this point.

---

If you can convince the users of your script to change the format of the environment variable, then you could split it based on a different separator:

```
ARGS="foo:Hello World:bar"
set -f # disable glob expansion
IFS=: args=( $ARGS )
set +f # re-enable it
```

Now you have an array `args` which you can use as above.

---

One (really nasty, **dangerous**) way to get your string into an array would be to use the notorious `eval`:

```
readarray -t args < <(eval printf '%s\\n' $ARGS)
```

Now you have an array `args` which you can use as in the previous examples.

But this is a big security problem:

```
ARGS="foo \"Hello, World\" bar \$(ls -l)"
```

Replace `ls -l` with any command that you want to execute...

Comment: This is great, but in my case I don't have control over `ARGS` it's given to me an an environment variable.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock Once you've demoted an array into a string, you will have to parse the string to turn it back into an array.

Comment: `IFS=: args=( $ARGS )` watch out for globs here. `set -f` might be a good idea.

Comment: @Pesa good idea, I edited to include that, thanks