# Single Quotations within a string in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a requirement to embed single quotes in a string. How can I achieve via shell scripting?

Sample Input: --connect jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S

Output:  --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S'

The format of this will always remain same.

Comment: If you know that the input will always start with `--connect `, just strip this part and wrap quotes around the rest. Or, split the input at the space (which also breaks it into `--connect` and *the rest*). In both cases, you can build the output together from these pieces, wrapping the second part in quotes. Or, replace the space by ` '` (space, quote) and append another single quote at the end.

Comment: Yes that's what I want, I am new to scripting, would you mind telling me how to achieve this?

Comment: Um, are you trying to add single-quotes so you can use it as part of a command? If so, don't do that; quotes are shell syntax, and will not be recognized in data (like variable values). See ["Variable containing multiple args with quotes in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454526/bash-variable-containing-multiple-args-with-quotes) and [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Also, don't follow any suggestions that use `eval` -- it's a huge bug magnet.

Comment: @Yogesh : I suggested 3 quite different alternatives. Which one do you want to approach? Edit  your posting, so this can be discussed properly. Also show your own attempt into solving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
echo "--connect jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S" | sed "s| jdbc| 'jdbc|g;s|$|'|g"
```

Comment: I have to convert only a part of string to single quote and not whole quote. Out put is  --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S'. The single quote starts with jdbc and not from --connect

Answer (score 0):

you could also escape them :

```
var=\'hello\'
echo $var
```

> Outputs 'hello'

Comment: I have to convert only a part of string to single quote and not whole quote. Out put is  --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S'. The single quote starts with jdbc and not from --connect

Comment: Then just simply enclose it into double quotes as @Gautam suggested :
`var="connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S'"`

Comment: The original input will be: --connect jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:12;DatabaseName=S with no quotes anywhere, not even at jdbc