# My bash execution keeps escaping my internal argument, no matter what

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, escaping

In my bash script, I need to run the following command:
`ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='argument1,argument2,argument3' out.mp4`

There are two major obstacles. First, the bash script always put subtitles=subtitles.srt in single quotes. The second, I need the single quotes for force_style arguments. But the bash keep escaping the single quotes no matter what. The result is usually something like this:

+ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf 'subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='(backslash)''arguments(backslash)'''

I have read tons of discussions. I tried using params array, escaping, executing with bash -c 'command', nothing was successful. Is there anybody who knows the trick? Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking at the output from a `set -x` trace? If so, that output you gave looks correct to me, it's just confusing if you're not used to how `set -x` shows arguments with weird characters -- especially single-quotes -- in them. Run `set -x; echo "This'll look weird"; set +x` and compare the trace output to what `echo` actually prints. Also, see muru's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658837/#658839) and Charles Duffy's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314359/#59314642).

Comment: @GordonDavisson As expected: this result is + echo 'This'(backslash)''ll look weird' (sorry for edits, this is the right version)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you know that "the bash script always put subtitles=subtitles.srt in single quotes". Bash doesn't add quotes by itself so what is it you're seeing and where to make you say that? Show a [mcve] in your question that we could copy/paste to run ourselves to reproduce the problem you're asking for help with. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting  for how to show input, output and code as Code Blocks.

Comment: The output resulting from using `set -x` includes quoting that sometimes causes confusion.  See [Bash inserting quotes into string before execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6087494/4154375) and [Why does bash add single quotes to unquoted failed pathname expansions in a command before executing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118403/264812).  `ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='argument1,argument2,argument3'" out.mp4` (untested) should do what you want, though the `set -x` output for it is very ugly.

Comment: that is exactly it, it works fine if it is correctly written. I did not know the set -x shows it in different way. Thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is really very useful to create reproducible example. The set -x option escaped the string and it is shown differently than it is executed. This was the confusion!