# Bash execute string as command without expanding escaped spaces

Tags: string, bash, command-line-arguments

I have an external executable that I need to pass arguments to. With a bash script, I have code that determines these arguments. Some arguments may have escaped spaces. 
I need to then execute that string, without expanding each of the arguments.

```sh
# ... some code that determines argument string
# the following is an example of the string

ARGSTR='./executable test\ file.txt arg2=true'
exec ${ARGSTR}
```

I must have the `$ARGSTR` be expanded so that I can pass arguments to `./executable`, but each of the arguments should not be expanded. I have tried quoting `"test file.txt"`, but this still does not pass it as one argument to `./executable`.

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Use a function instead of a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454526/variable-containing-multiple-args-with-quotes-in-bash), and many others. (Warning: some of those have answers involving `eval` -- don't be tempted, `eval` usually causes weird bugs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Us an array instead of a string:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ARGSTR=('./executable' 'test file.txt' 'arg2=true')
exec "${ARGSTR[@]}"
```

See:

#### [BashFAQ-50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44055875/7939871

Answer (score 1):

This may achieve what you wanted :

```
ARGSTR='./executable test\ file.txt arg2=true'
exec bash -c "exec ${ARGSTR}"
```