# How to expand variable in bash tar command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tar

I have a tar command to create .tar.gz file. It looks like below:

```
exclude="--exclude='.cache' --exclude='.composer' --exclude='.local' --exclude='.config'"

tar "$exclude" -czf "$backupsDir/$timestamp-home.tar.gz" /home
```

The problem is the $exclude variable in not evaluated and excluded directories are still in the archive. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Argument lists should be stored in arrays, not strings.

Comment: See: [Variable containing multiple args with quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7454526/7939871)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think the one I mentioned is a better duplicate parent to link this to. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7454526/7939871

Comment: @LéaGris, I've updated the list of duplicates, though I'm wary of the level of pro-`eval` sentiment in the answers to the new addition; folks who don't understand the risks are liable to end up in trouble.

Comment: Thanks it works. In my opinion the @CharlesDuffy's answer is cleaner and easier to understand.