# How do I pass quoted shell variables as arguments correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip

As part of a build pipeline I have a shell script that zips up a directory. I want to use a variable to define which patterns should be ignored.

I'm doing something like this:

```
IGNORE='"*.md" "some-folder/*"'
zip -x $IGNORE -r my-zip.zip ./*
```

Which doesn't appear to work, the ignored files and folders are still included in the zip archive.

This does work if I create the command and then pipe it through to `sh` though, so I'm confident that the variable contains the correct values:

```
echo "zip -x $IGNORE -r my-zip.zip ./*" | sh
```

I think it might be something to do with the quotes, since this works as expected without them. However this fails as soon as I attempt to add more than 1 pattern to `IGNORE`.

```
IGNORE=*.md
zip -x $IGNORE -r my-zip.zip ./*
```

What am I missing in order to be able to pass these patterns correctly quoted?

Edit: this does also *not* appear to work as an array, as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454526/variable-containing-multiple-args-with-quotes-in-bash).

```
IGNORE='"*.md" "some-folder/*"'
EXCLUDE=($IGNORE)
zip -x ${EXCLUDE[@]} -r my-zip.zip ./*
```

Comment: I don't think so, the top voted answer there assumes I can create an array by passing in multiple variables like `args=( "$f1" "$f2" )`. I don't think it's possible to do something similar here?

I could maybe do something to turn `$IGNORE` into an array first? I think this question is different from the one linked though.

Comment: you need an array here: `exclude=("*.md" "./some-folder/*"); zip -x "${exclude[@]}" -r myzip.zip ./*`

Comment: See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an  explanation of why it's unsafe to use ALL_UPPERCASE variable names like `IGNORE`.

Comment: @Fravadona - doesn't appear to work when turned into an array either, edited to add failing example with an array.

Comment: @pjh - thanks for the heads-up, good to know!

Comment: @TomDavies  Is the excluding of `"some-folder/*"` that doesn't work?

Comment: @Fravadona - nope I see both "README.md" and "some-folder/.." being added to the ZIP. The array converting definitely works though, I can access \*.md and some-folder/* using array indices if I just echo them out.

Comment: There are several problems with the code in the edit.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds some of them.  The code provided by @Fravadona in a comment is good.

Comment: Can't answer since this has now been closed, but it turns out that the reason this doesn't work is because of the globbing.

The "some-folder/*" gets expanded, rather than passed as a pattern to `zip`. Turning this off with `set -f` before turning `$include` into an array resolves this.

Comment: Using a single string to initialize the array doesn't work in general.  Using `set -f` may work here, but it isn't sufficient in general.  The reliable way to do it is to initialize the array with the literal arguments.  All you need to do is to copy and paste the correct code that Fravadona provided.

Comment: I can't initialise with the literal arguments, they're sourced from a GitLab variable. I need to turn that value into an array. If I could do that, yes, it would be done already. This is why I asked a new question.

Comment: The answer of @Fravadona is not correct. This solution does not produce the result that is implied when using the `some-folder/*` pattern with zip command. However, the array option will work. The important point is to prevent pattern expansion. Considering @Tom's last question, the solution would be: `read -a exclude_array<<<$IGNORE; zip -x "${exclude_array[@]}" -r my-zip.zip ./*`

Comment: @seeker `<<<$IGNORE` is not a good idea, that will convert single/multiple spaces/tabs/newlines to single space.

Comment: @Fravadona, you're right about space squeezing. But this is not a problem, neither for the filename patterns, nor for the command line arguments.