# Invoking command with arguments from variable

Tags: sh, quoting

I have a list of arguments, some which contain spaces, stored in a variable. When the command is invoked the arguments are not interpreted correctly. Here is a minimal example which illustrates the problem:

```
$ cat test.sh
echo $1
echo $2
$ sh test.sh foo "bar baz"
foo
bar baz
$ args='foo "bar baz"'
$ sh test.sh $args
foo
"bar
```

How should I pass *args* to make test.sh print this instead?

```
foo
bar baz
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable containing multiple args with quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454526/variable-containing-multiple-args-with-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interpret shell code that one constructs (incl grabbing from a variable), one uses `eval`.

```bash
eval "sh test.sh $args"
```

But is it really the best idea to put code in a variable?