# Bash script builds correct $cmd but fails to execute complex stream

Tags: bash, cut

This short script scrapes some log files daily to create a simple extract. It works from the command line and when I echo the $cmd and copy/paste, it also works. But it will breaks when I try to execute from the script itself.

I know this is a nightmare of patterns that I could probably improve, but am I missing something simple to just execute this correctly?

```
#!/bin/bash
priorday=$(date --date yesterday +"%Y-%m-%d")
outputfile="/home/CCHCS/da14/$priorday""_PROD_message_processing_times.txt"
cmd="grep 'Processed inbound' /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog* | cut -f5,6,12,16,18 -d\" \" | grep '^"$priorday"' | sed 's/\,/\./' | sed 's/ /\t/g' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\t/\1 /' | sed 's/  / /g' | sort >$outputfile"
printf "command to execute:\n"
echo $cmd
printf "\n"
$cmd
```

ouput:

> > ./make_log_extract.sh command to execute: grep 'Processed inbound' /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.1
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.10
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.11
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.12
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.2
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.3
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.4
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.5
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.6
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.7
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.8
> >     /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog.log.9 | cut -f5,6,12,16,18 -d" " | grep
> >     '^2014-01-30' | sed 's/\,/./' | sed 's/ /\t/g' | sed -r
> >     's/([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)\t/\1 /' | sed 's/ / /g' | sort
> >     /home/CCHCS/da14/2014-01-30_PROD_message_processing_times.txt
>
> grep: 5,6,12,16,18: No such file or directory

Comment: Basically, try not to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794728/variables-as-commands-in-bash-scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [grebneke comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484384/bash-script-builds-correct-cmd-but-fails-to-execute-complex-stream#comment32428041_21484384), do not store the command and then execute it.

What you can do is to execute it but firstly print it: [Bash: Print each command before executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750463/1983854)

```
priorday=$(date --date yesterday +"%Y-%m-%d")
outputfile="/home/CCHCS/da14/$priorday""_PROD_message_processing_times.txt"

set -o xtrace # <-- set printing mode "on"
grep 'Processed inbound' /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog* | cut -f5,6,12,16,18 -d\" \" | grep '^"$priorday"' | sed 's/\,/\./' | sed 's/ /\t/g' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\t/\1 /' | sed 's/  / /g' | sort >$outputfile"
set +o xtrace # <-- revert to normal
```

Comment: +1, what is the difference between `set -x` and `set -o xtrace`, if any?

Comment: From what I see in http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html, it is exactly the same. Just short & long notation.

Comment: Single-character shell options can also be used when starting `bash`: `bash -x` is equivalent to starting `bash` then executing `set -x`.

Comment: Thanks; very helpful. I was able to bracket the command with print command and then work through each piped command to get the syntax right:

#grep 'Processed inbound' /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog* | cut -f5,6,12,16,18 -d' ' | grep '^"$priorday"' | sed 's/\,/\./' | sed 's/ /\t/g' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\t/\1 /' | sed 's/  / /g' | sort >$outputfile

grep 'Processed inbound' /home/rules/care/logs/RootLog* | cut -f5,6,12,16,18 -d' ' | grep "^$priorday"  | sed 's/\,/\./'  | sed 's/ /\t/g'  | sed -r 's/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)\t/\1 /' | sed 's/  / /g' | sort >$outputfile

`