# Get columns name and write it into a file

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

Hi guys i wrote a bash script that execute a query e and print the result into a file but it doesn't work

```
source ../db.config
msqlcmd="mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -s -B -q"
echo "USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;\nSELECT * FROM COLUMNS" | $mysqlcmd > ../tmpsql/columns.txt
```

Into the db.config there are the credential to access to db

Comment: *but it doesn't work* means ? can you show expected output and your output ?

Comment: i don't get no output in console. I expect that it creates a file with the result of the query, it creates the file, but doesn't print any result

Comment: [No "_Hi_" please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Don't put commands in variables.

Comment: @Cyrus Well said ! A point to be noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel to get mysql login credentials. Use [mysql_config_editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) to store your credentials encrypted in ~/.mylogin.cnf, then you can do the whole thing in a simple one-liner e.g.

```
mysql -s -B -q -e "select * from information_schema.columns" | tee ./tmpsql/columns.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put command in variables as [[ **this** ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794814/1620779) answer nicely summarizes.

A [[ **heredoc** ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) is your friend here.

```
mysql -u "$db_user" -p "$db_pass" -s -B -q <<-EOF > ../tmpsql/columns.txt
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT * FROM COLUMNS;
EOF
```

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

---

<sup>**Note:** Don't use full uppercase identifiers like `$DB_USER` for user defined variables as it may conflict with built-in shell variables. Double quoting variables is also a standard practice.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
source ../db.config
echo -e "USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;\nSELECT * FROM COLUMNS" | mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -s -B -q > ../tmpsql/columns.txt
```

Comment: Don't you need the `-e` option with `echo` for the `\n` to be interpreted?

Comment: That `eval` is dubious pal. I suggest don't go there. `:-/`

Comment: removing it ;-) let's keep it simple and stupid (and working hehehe) thanks

Comment: Hmm.. The op mentioned in a comment to the question that cyrus' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365639/get-columns-name-and-write-it-into-a-file/48365689#comment83717949_48365639) already solved his problem. I am wondering how he got it working without `-e` flag. It may be that he is an OS where interpreting backslashes may be the default behaviour.